tinytex PATH, installation via R
I have installed tinytex via the tinytex R package with the default add_path = TRUE on Windows 11. According to the documentation, this adds the executable to the system environment variable PATH. So, I should be able to use tinytex outside R. However, software outside R does apparently not find it. The LaTeX Workshop extension in VS Code e.g. complains about a missing executable and throws errors such as 'latexmk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
This post's recommendation of restarting the machine did not help: R tinytex PATH-Variable.
I can compile tex files from within R. How do I get my tinytex installation to work outside R?

As long as R knows where your tinytex path is, you can find it through R and add it to your PATH environment variable. For example:
(tiny_tex_path <- tinytex::tinytex_root())
# [1] "/home/sam/.TinyTeX"
(full_path <- dir(paste0(tiny_tex_path, "/bin"), full.names = TRUE))
# [1] "/home/sam/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux"

The latter is the directory you need to add to your PATH. I see you're using Windows so your path will be slightly different. Let's pretend for the purpose of this example that it's "C:\Program Files\TinyTex\bin\x86_64".
Add the path to your PATH - Windows
Find your PowerShell profile. It is probably in Documents/WindowsPowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. If this file does not exist, create it. Then simply edit this in a text editor to add a line which adds the tinytex path to your PATH environment variable, e.g:
$env:PATH += ";C:\Program Files\TinyTex\bin\x86_64"

This profile is loaded every time you start PowerShell. You can test whether it has worked by opening a new PowerShell window and entering pdflatex --version. If rather than an error, you get something like below, it has worked:
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)
kpathsea version 6.4.0

Add the path to your PATH - Linux
For completeness, here are Linux directions, using the path from above. Assuming you're using bash, you can just add to ~/.bashrc:
export PATH="/home/sam/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"

The same process applies with other shells to the .bashrc equivalent, e.g. for zsh amend your .zshrc. As with Windows, you will need to source this file or restart your shell to update your PATH.
